# games have split second freezes every 30/60 seconds

Tags: windows-10, freeze, gaming, fps

asking this here again, last post didnt get any awnsers. i really appreciate any help.
the issue is really hard to explain because its so random. i get freezes where my game just freezes in for example pubg, it lasts for about 1 second and then it usually takes about a minute to happen again. but the amount of these freezes and how bad they are also randomly changes, sometimes theyre almost not there and other times its unplayable.
i had this issue on my main pc first, it still had pretty old components at the time so i replaced every part. but the issues were still there.
i then tried another pc that i used in a different house, it didnt have the issue and used it in the same house as my main pc. and then my second pc got the same issues.
im pretty much out of ideas, im not an expert at all. ive checked if maybe my pc wasnt getting enough power, but i checked it and it was stable.

i would really appreciate some help, ive been trying to fix it for so long and im pretty much out of hope. thanks in advance and sorry for the bad spelling/grammar.

*im using cabled ethernet
router: Experia box v8, Astroria Networks VGV7519

Comment: i added it to the post, i hope thats what you ment

Comment: Just want to make sure; are the PCs connected by Ethernet cables to the router, or using WiFi? I ask, for the WiFi from that https://www.consumentenbond.nl/router/producten/arcadyan/vgv7519-experia-box-v8 is 2.4GHz only, and therefore congestion would be problematic.

Comment: ethernet cables to the router, 100% sure.

Comment: In your other post you said you replaced P.C. hardware, except for the GPU. Does that mean you tried a new motherboard too?

Comment: Sounds more like driver timeout than a connectivity issue. Get fresh drivers directly from the chipset maker, not windows, & test on lower [or higher] graphics settings. Some hardware optimisations depend on your GPU [which you didn't specify] & if the GPU is of a certain age/spec can sometimes be faster at higher settings.

Comment: DrZoo, in my main pc i also replaced my motherboard yes. but i didnt to the testing on that pc.

Comment: Tetsujin, the gpu in the main pc was a 1060 3g. and my second pc has a 1050ti. they are both bought new. should i download chipset drivers from my motherboards support page? or do you mean something else. thanks

Comment: Directly from NVidia, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try clearing out your DNS Cache a la https://www.maketecheasier.com/flush-dns-cache-windows10/
2. Change your DNS Server to 8.8.4.4. and 8.8.8.8 (Google's free-to-use DNS Servers) following https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10 as your ISP's DNS Server can be slow.
3. Reset your router.
4. Replace your DSL cable from the router to the phone jack on the wall.
5. Unplug all the phones in your house for a test and see if the lag goes away; should that help, it's time for new DSL filters.
6. Replace the in-wall Ethernet from router to PC.

Comment: do you have a good guide for changing the DNS server?
thank you so much for all the help

Comment: did all 5 of them, they didnt seem to fix it. could it still be my hardware?

Comment: Hardware, in this case, encompasses the network as well as the PC. Since it happens with two different PC, could I ask you to try a new Ethernet cable from your router to the wall, and another new one on the faster PC?

Comment: replacing the ethernet cable would be alot of work, theyre ran trough the entire house in the wall. i guess i could try a new cable from the socket to the pc

Comment: i tried playing the witcher 3 and i had no issues at all, game was smooth except for lower fps at intensive moments. pretty much has to be a network thing right?

Comment: How about a temporary Ethernet run outside the wall? I'd make sure new cable improves your performance before pulling in through the walls. And, did you try unplugging all the phones in your house for a test to see if the lag goes away; should that help, it's time for new DSL filters, far easier than replacing cabling!

Comment: tried another ethernet directly from the router to my pc. tried pubg and didnt have any issues, even dropping into high player areas. then i tried tarkov and didnt have any issues either. im gonna keep testing for a while and see what happens